# GvrViewer.Instance.Triggered seems to be true during two frames

Tags: google-cardboard, google-vr

The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/reference/class/gvr-viewer#triggered) says:

> True for exactly one complete frame after each pull.

However the following Log is executed twice per tap on the screen:

```
void Update(){
    if (GvrViewer.Instance.Triggered { 
          Debug.Log("Tap detected");
    }
}
```

A workaround could be removing the `private` from `public bool Triggered { get; private set; }` in *GvrViewer*. Then setting it to `false` manually within the above if clause. It would not be a very elegant solution though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. There are 2 objects with that script attached. That's why it was executed twice!